# How can I get the list of unique terms from a specific field in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I have an index from a large corpus with several fields. Only one these fields contain text.
I need to extract the unique words from the whole index based on this field.
Does anyone know how I can do that with Lucene in java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [term vectors](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/fileformats.html#Term%20Vectors) (a set of all the words that were in the field and the number of times each word was used, excluding stop words). You'll use IndexReader's [getTermFreqVector(docid, field)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FilterIndexReader.html#getTermFreqVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) for each document in the index, and populate a `HashSet` with them.

The alternative would be to use [terms()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#terms%28%29) and pick only terms for the field you're interested in:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index);
TermEnum terms = reader.terms();
Set<String> uniqueTerms = new HashSet<String>();
while (terms.next()) {
        final Term term = terms.term();
        if (term.field().equals("field_name")) {
                uniqueTerms.add(term.text());
        }
}
```

This is not the optimal solution, you're reading and then discarding all other fields. There's a class `Fields` in Lucene 4, that returns [terms(field)](http://search-lucene.com/jd/lucene/org/apache/lucene/index/Fields.html#terms%28java.lang.String%29) only for a single field.

Comment: I know this funtion. But I need the unique words across the whole corpus. not per document.

Comment: yes, thanks I am using the terms() but it is giving me back everything that has been index. I couldn find a place to tell it to pick only terms for a specific field. do you have any reference on that?

Comment: if (term.field().equals("field_name")) {...} for the field you want :)

Comment: Even on Lucene 3, you don't have to scan the terms of all fields for this. This seems to be undocumented, but `reader.terms(new Term(fieldName, termText))` will return the `Term`-s ordered by field name, and among the terms from the same field ordered by term text. So if you use `terms.term(fieldName, "")` above, and `break` on the first occasion when `!term.field().equals(fieldName)`, you got exactly what you wanted. But since this is undocumented, won't it break one day? As far as I see Lucene's own `WildcardQuery` build on this too, and it's unlikely that Lucene 3 will change much anymore.

Comment: @milan For what reason did you declare the variable `term` as `final`? Any performance reason?

Comment: @basZero i don't remember why, but looking at the code, it'd be both for performance reasons and also code readability. vars should've been final by default imo

Comment: The terms vectors might or might not be stored, this isnt what is meant in the question

Answer (score 28):

If you are using the Lucene 4.0 api, you need to get the fields out of the index reader. The Fields then offers the way to get the terms for each field in the index. Here is an example of how to do that:

```
        Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(indexReader);
        Terms terms = fields.terms("field");
        TermsEnum iterator = terms.iterator(null);
        BytesRef byteRef = null;
        while((byteRef = iterator.next()) != null) {
            String term = new String(byteRef.bytes, byteRef.offset, byteRef.length);

        }
```

Eventually, for the new version of Lucene you can get the string from the BytesRef calling:

```
       byteRef.utf8ToString();
```

instead of

```
       new String(byteRef.bytes, byteRef.offset, byteRef.length);
```

If you want to get the document frequency, you can do :

```
       int docFreq = iterator.docFreq();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for modern versions of Lucene.

Answer (score 3):

Same result, just a little cleaner, is to use the `LuceneDictionary` in the `lucene-suggest` package. It takes care of a field that does not contain any terms by returning an `BytesRefIterator.EMPTY`. That will save you a NPE :)

```
    LuceneDictionary ld = new LuceneDictionary( indexReader, "field" );
    BytesRefIterator iterator = ld.getWordsIterator();
    BytesRef byteRef = null;
    while ( ( byteRef = iterator.next() ) != null )
    {
        String term = byteRef.utf8ToString();
    }
```

Comment: In the meanwhile getWordsIterator() is replaced by getEntryIterator()

Comment: Disadvantage of this approach is the the lucene-suggest package is needed. So if not used, i prefer the solution of @pokeRex110

Answer (score 2):

As of Lucene 7+ the above and some related links are obsolete.

Here's what's current:

```
// IndexReader has leaves, you'll iterate through those
int leavesCount = reader.leaves().size();
final String fieldName = "content";

for(int l = 0; l < leavesCount; l++) {
  System.out.println("l: " + l);
  // specify the field here ----------------------------->
  TermsEnum terms = reader.leaves().get(l).reader().terms(fieldName).iterator();
  // this stops at 20 just to sample the head
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    // and to get it out, here -->
    final Term content = new Term(fieldName, BytesRef.deepCopyOf(terms.next()));
    System.out.println("i: " + i + ", term: " + content);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers using `TermsEnum` and `terms.next()` have a subtle off by one bug. This is because the `TermsEnum` already points to the first term, so `while(terms.next())` will cause the first term to be skipped.

Instead use a for loop:

```
TermEnum terms = reader.terms();
for(Term term = terms.term(); term != null; terms.next(), term = terms.term()) {
    // do something with the term
}
```

To modify the code from the accepted answer:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index);
TermEnum terms = reader.terms();
Set<String> uniqueTerms = new HashSet<String>();
for(Term term = terms.term(); term != null; terms.next(), term = terms.term()) {
        if (term.field().equals("field_name")) {
                uniqueTerms.add(term.text());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different compared to the solution of @pokeRex110  (tested with Lucene 9.3.0)

```
Terms terms = MultiTerms.getTerms(indexReader, "title");
if (terms != null) {
    TermsEnum iter = terms.iterator();
    BytesRef byteRef = null;
    while ((byteRef = iter.next()) != null) {
        System.out.printf("%s (freq=%s)%n", 
            byteRef.utf8ToString(), 
            iter.docFreq()
        );
    }
}
```