# Lucene: Getting terms from an unstored field

Tags: lucene

Is there any way to retrieve all the terms in a particular field which is unfortunately not stored. I can not rebuild the index. Positional based information is not necessary. I just need the list of terms.

*UPDATE*

I've built a sample index with one stored, another unstored field and tested it with Luke. I was wondering whether I could get access to all terms just like Luke did. This may not be the brightest idea, but might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene uses two different concepts: Indexing and Storing. If you want to extract the terms, you dont need to store anything. You can use luke, as well as iterate over the terms through the API. For the java API you can use  [1]: [How can I get the list of unique terms from a specific field in Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910008/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-unique-terms-from-a-specific-field-in-lucene/13911747#13911747).

Comment: that's what I ended up doing in last summer :)

Answer (score 0):

Luke is Open Source, so just look at how Luke does it.